# Распознавание изображений python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

Мне нужно, чтобы программа могла распознать изображение: например, я даю ей какую-нибудь картинку, а она мне выдавала координаты этой картинки на другой картинке (ну вы поняли). **Именно для питона 3.2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если одно из изображений в точности (побитово) содержится в другом, то нужно считать оба массива и искать совпадения битовых строк. Если нет, то нужны более мощные средства. Можно подключить библиотеку [OpenCV](https://web.archive.org/web/20130803074437/http://opencv.willowgarage.com:80/wiki/PythonInterface), можно [NymPy](https://numpy.org/). Для NymPy потребуется

1. Считать изображения с помощью [Python Imaging Library](https://python-pillow.org/)
2. Преобразовать в массивы, потребляемые библиотекой, и работать с фильтрами библиотеки.

Comment: мне нужно именно узнать координаты одного изображения на другом(хотя бы одну точку)
все библиотеки которые вы назвали не работают с з веткой питона(((

Comment: Разве NumPy не поддерживает Python 3.2 ?
[Package numpy 1.6.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy)
[NumPy 1.5.0 Release Notes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files//NumPy/1.5.0/NOTES.txt/view)

Comment: спасибо! ноя все же решил пересесть на второй питон)